# Certification Exam Maintenence Fees

Tags: certification

I've just checked WebAssessor and seen that I can register for the Salesforce Certified Force.com Developer - Winter '16 Release Exam. The description says that it's:

> Successful completion of the Salesforce Certified Developer Winter '16 Release Exam is required for all Salesforce Certified Force.com Developers, Advanced Developers, and Technical Architects.

With a price tag of $100.

Is this a maintenance exam? I haven't had to pay before to maintain my credential (Dev-401). I'm confused here as to whether or not this is a maintence exam or something new for Salesforce? Do they charge $100 a year for being certified?

If it is a maintenence exam charging $100 for it is incredibly cheeky!

Comment: you have to pay $100 yearly for each credential exam. And yes this is a maintenance exam

Comment: The first year (after completing a cert) is free of charge for the maintenance. After that you have to pay $100 per year (for each credential).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is an annual USD 100 maintenance fee for all Salesforce
>   Certified individuals who hold the following credentials:

Salesforce Certified Administrator

Salesforce Certified Force.com Developer

> If you hold both credentials, the annual cost to maintain them is USD
>   200. The annual maintenance fee also includes the cost to maintain any higher-level credentials.

I wonder how you haven't paid the maintenance fee and maintained the credentials.

Comment: I've just seen this. I passed on the 31st January last year so haven't had to do this outside of the free maintenance ones until now.

Comment: @poet That explains :), I was looking at your reputation so assumed you are a veteran certified pro

Comment: Far from it! Still consider myself an amateur on SFSE. Try to help where I can though. :)